# Protecting certain cells in Excel - C# Epplus

Tags: c#, .net, excel, spreadsheet, epplus

I have a program exporting a spreadsheet, containing headers and some data. I need to protect the headers, but leave the data cells editable.

The problem is, upon setting the worksheet as protected, all the cells become read-only.

So, the approach I am using is to check each of the cells below the header to see if they are not empty, and unlock them if so.

```
public void formatSpreadsheet(OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet ws)
{
    // autofit columns
    for (int i = 1; i <= ws.Dimension.End.Column; i++)
    {
        ws.Column(i).AutoFit();
    }

    // protect headers/metadata
    ws.Protection.IsProtected = true;
    int row = HEADER_ROW_OFFSET;
    int col = 1;


    while (ws.Cells[row,col].Value != null)
    {

        while (ws.Cells[row,col].Value != null)
        {
            ws.Cells[row, col].Style.Locked = false;
            col++;
        }
        row++;
    }

}
```

Testing for null values like so:

```
if (ws.Cells[row,col].Value != null)  ws.Cells[row,col].Style.Locked = false;
```

doesn't work.

I have also tried ToString() on the cell values, and it doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't the locking, but your loop that goes through the cells:

```
while (ws.Cells[row,col].Value != null)
```

As soon as it hits an empty cell, it will immediately exit the block, and nothing else will be performed.

The following should work fine:

```
// Lock the worksheet. You can do this here, or in the end. Doesn't really matter.
ws.Protection.IsProtected = true;

// Assuming `HEADER_ROW_OFFSET` is the first row that's not a header,
// we first define a "data" range as starting from the first column of that row, 
// to the very last used row & column.
var dataCells = ws.Cells[HEADER_ROW_OFFSET, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Row, ws.Dimension.End.Column];

// Now go through each cell in that range,
foreach (var cel in dataCells)
{
    // and unlock when it has content.
    if (cel.Value != null) cel.Style.Locked = false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Locking the entire spreadsheet, automatically permanently locks the cells.
If you want to only have certain cells locked, go trough the spreadsheet and lock them (leaving the spreadsheet  itself unlocked)

Comment: I tried locking individual cells, as you suggested, like so: ```worksheet.Cells[
"A1"].Style.Locked = true;``` It doesn't seem to work without locking the entire spreadsheet first.

Comment: While this is true when you're using a keyboard and mouse on Excel, EPPlus has no problems whatsoever unlocking cells even if the sheet is protected.

Comment: Correct, but I was referring to what the other answerer was saying. They mentioned that trying to lock individual cells should work without locking the entire spreadsheet. In principle, I should be able to unlock certain cells even when the entire sheet is locked, but the problem is my approach, checking for null values, does not seem to work.

Comment: @acsice sorry, that comment was directed at the answer, not you :)